# Embedded Image URL in Table View - How Display Page Immediately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, uitableview, uiimageview

Apologies if this is too abstract, but hopefully someone can help. I have a table detail view which contains a UIimageView which loads a JPG from a web URL.

The problem is that the entire detail view does not display until this URL has loaded, which can take a few seconds.

Is there any way to display the view immediately and then let the image "catch up" and load when it is done ?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Apologies - found this excellent thread :

[View showed delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699613/view-showed-delay)